# Mutation issue while Inserting into array - Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a state object that looks like this.

```
 this.state = {
      formValues: {},
    };
```

After some processing, formValues contains the following.

```
 this.state = {
          formValues: {
              q1: value 1,
              q2: value 2  
          },
        };
```

Now i have q3 inside formValues which is an array of values. When i try to push the value like as follows

```
let q3 = e.target.name,
    arrayValues = [1,2,3]
formValues[q3].push(arrayValues)
```

I am getting the following error while submitting the data

> Uncaught Error: A state mutation was detected between dispatches

It looks like there is a problem with pushing data into array. Any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a copy and update the state with `setState` instead of direct state mutation with `push`.

```
this.setState(prevState => ({
  formValues: {
    ...prevState.formValues,
    [q3]: prevState.formValues[q3].concat(arrayValues),
  },
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming that you always want to push to your array such as in your use case:

```javasript
const { formValues } = this.state
const arrayValues = [1,2,4]
const newFormValues = { ...formValues, q3: [...formValues[q3], arrayValues]}
this.setState({ formValues: newFormValues })
```

but much better if you control directly the value of q3:

```javasript
const { formValues } = this.state
const arrayValues = [1,2,4]
const newFormValues = { ...formValues, q3: arrayValues}
this.setState({ formValues: newFormValues })
```